# division not working with continuous query in influxdb

Tags: influxdb

I am trying to generate a continuous query in influxDB. The query is to fetch the hits per second by doing (1/response time) of the value which i am already getting for another series (say series1).

Here is the query:
select (1000/value) as value from series1 group by time(1s) into api.HPS;

My problem is that the query "select (1000/value) as value from series1 group by time(1s)" works fine and provide me results but as soon as I store the result into continuous query, it starts to give me parse error.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to give any concrete advice without the actual parse error returned and perhaps the relevant log lines. Try providing those to the mailing list at influxdb@googlegroups.com or email them to support@influxdb.com.

There's an email on the Google Group that might be relevant, too. https://groups.google.com/d/msgid/influxdb/c99217b3-fdab-4684-b656-a5f5509ed070%40googlegroups.com

Have you tried using whitespace between the values and the operator? E.g. `select (1000 / value) AS value...`.